R2 DeleteObjectCommand Always Returns 204 - Even for Non-Existent or Random Keys
I'm experiencing an unusual behavior with the DeleteObjectCommand in the AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3) when interacting with R2. When I call DeleteObjectCommand, it consistently returns a 204 status code, even when:

The object key is a completely random string
The object does not actually exist in the bucket

For example:
const params = {
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Key: 'totally-nonexistent-random-string'
};
const response = await client.send(new DeleteObjectCommand(params));
// response.$metadata.httpStatusCode is always 204

Is this the expected behavior for R2? How can I reliably:

Verify if an object was actually deleted?
Ensure the key I'm trying to delete is valid?
Distinguish between a successful deletion and a no-op?


Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
